# Cyclotomic Extensions

Tags: field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

The following statement seems to be quite easy but somehow I can't manage to prove it:

Let $n = l_1^{v_1}...l_n^{v_n}$ be a prime decomposition of the natural number n. Let $\xi$ be a primitive n-th root of unity. Then $\xi_i = \xi^{n/{l_i^{v_i}}}$ is a primite $l_i^{v_i}$-th root of unity and one has $\mathbb{Q}(\xi) = \mathbb{Q}(\xi_1)...\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n)$ and (the part I don't understand):

$$ \mathbb{Q}(\xi_1)...\mathbb{Q}(\xi_{i-1}) \cap \mathbb{Q}(\xi_i) = \mathbb{Q} $$

To me it it kind of makes sense that this holds, because any product involving only powers of $l_1,...l_{i-1}$ is coprime to $l_i$ but I can't manage to prove it nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Not only $l_1,...,l{i-1}$ is coprime to $l_i$, but it happens that you can not construct a chord of a polygon $l_i$ from the other examples.  Since the cyclotomic set $Q(i)$ corresponds to the span of chords of {i}, and this by the root $\exp \pi/l$.

The trick here is that any of the roots of $Q(l_i)$ will solve the equation $x^{l_i}+1=0$.  This has several factors including $x^1+1=0$ (which leads to $Q$), but nothing in the set of numbers coprime to $l_1$ can solve $x^{l_1}+1=0$.

The solution here is not dissimilar to that of $10^{l_i}-1$ shares with ${10^n}-1$, only the common factor $10-1$.  It is because both cyclotomic numbers and bases call down to a common structure, and the proof lies therein.

Comment: Dear Wendy, thank you for your answer. What do you mean by the "chord of a polygon $l_i$" and the roots of $\mathbb{Q}(l_i)$? Since $l_i$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: For example, suppose $l_i$ = 9.  Then the cyclotomic numbers are the solutions to x^18=1.  The span of these numbers form on the complex plane, those steps you can make in unit steps of 18ths of a circle.  You can make a polygon of side 9, by changing the angle by 2 units each step (eg 0, 2, 4, 6)/18.  The real part of the cyclotomic numbers are the span of chords (Z9 in my notation), of a polygon of unit side, (ie 2sin2pi/9,  2sin4pi/9, 2sin6pi/9)  and the complex part is made of this part and 1, exp(pi/9).

Comment: I worked out cyclotomic numbers from first principles, so the symbols confuse me.  The span of the equation x^n+1=0, form a complex integer system CZn.  These are the cyclomic numbers.  The real part is Zn, which is Z[1, 2sin(pi/n)], which corresponds to the set Z[1,a,b,c,...], where 1, a, b, c, ... is the lengths of the distances between vertex 0 and vertex 1, 2, 3, 4... of a polygon.

I use this quite a bit in scratching around hyperbolic tilings etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with this concept. By $\mathbb{Q}({x})$, I mean the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $x$.